# JPEG compression in gdal_translate: wrong JPEG library version

Tags: ubuntu, compression, gdal

I tried to reduce the size of a simple hillshade geotiff by manipulating a compression switch of gdal_translate command, inspired by [this](http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2015/02/geotiff-compression-for-dummies.html) great blog entry. However, running command with `-co COMPRESS=JPEG` results with the following well known error:

`ERROR 1: JPEGLib:Wrong JPEG library version: library is 62, caller expects 80`

I made sure I deleted every single instance 6- based libjpeg library and installed every possible 8-based libjpeg library, but the problem still persists. I have GDAL version 2.0.0. running on Ubuntu 16.04.1 Xenial.

Has anybody run into the same problem?

Is it the input (geotiff) or dependencies related issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I haven't found a solution to the original problem, but I did find a sweet workaround to apply a JPEG compression to the TIF raster which was my original problem anyways.

For some reason, calling a gdal_translate from within Python's [GDAL API](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/) doesn't have problem with `"COMPRESS=JPEG"` option. So, here is what worked for me:

```
from osgeo import gdal
ds = gdal.Open("Raster.tif")
ds = gdal.Translate("Raster_compressed.tif", ds, creationOptions=['COMPRESS=JPEG'])
```

Answer (score -1):

Check what libraries are referenced from gdal_translate:

```
ldd /bin/gdal_translate
ldd /bin/gdal_translate | grep jpeg
```

Check where are your library symlinks pointing at, as described [here](https://www.webhostingneeds.com/Wrong_JPEG_library_version:_library_is_62,_caller_expects_80):

List all files in your library folders and grep for the library you are lloking for:

```
cd /usr/lib64/
ls -la | grep jpeg

cd /usr/local/lib
ls -la | grep jpeg

cd /usr/lib
ls -la | grep jpeg
```

Make sure all your symlinks are pointing to the right version:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       17 Mar  8 09:54 libjpeg.so -> libjpeg.so.62.0.0*
```

Should be

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       17 Mar  8 09:54 libjpeg.so -> libjpeg.so.8.3.0*
```

Install the libraries that provide the correct version or create the symlinks manually.

Comment: Tried this solution, but can't proceed since I have (almost) empty /etc/ld.so.conf... I have deleted every single appearance of libjpeg6* on computer (via locate, dpkg --list, ldconfig -p), reinstalled libjpegs and gdal all over again,... running out of ideas...

Comment: @MarjanModerc Can you please post the result of the commands above?